# How to keep the node debugger connected across code changes

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I start a Node.js process with the `--inspect` flag then I get a URL  in the console for me to debug the application using Chrome dev tools.

eg

> Debugger listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:9229/fa66d6b2-2011-4e4f-bafc-fc9a300a36d5

If I make a change to my application, I need to restart the application process, and this results in a completely new debug URL.

This is inconvenient because I already have Chrome dev tools pointing at the old URL.

How can I have the process automatically restart on application source code  changes **and** maintain the same dev tools debugging session to avoid the need to manually reconfigure dev tools for every change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Node Inspector Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj?hl=en) plugin. It has the ability to listen to the inspector and automatically open in a new tab. This is a big part of my development workflow.